# sox library call main, and error is can't open input file `1', why?

Tags: android, sox, libsox

I use the sox library on android, and i use the command to change the channel of mp3 file

[image]

```
sox /storage/emulated/0/Music/Drivethrough.mp3 -c 1 /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.tian.xxx/cache/temp/results.mp3
```

when i run it, display

```
can't open input file `1': No such file or directory
```

and my code is:

```
int mymain(int argc, char **argv, const char *tempPath);
```

here is the code detail: https://github.com/pxhbug123/SoxLibInAndroid/blob/master/soxcommandlibrary/src/main/sox/src/sox.c#L2908

I do not know why ?

I use this method to call sox
https://github.com/pxhbug123/SoxLibInAndroid/blob/master/soxcommandlibrary/src/main/sox/src/JniNative.c#L265

Answer (score 0):

solved it.  just replace the '-c' to '--channels'